# Reorder one sequence into another one through swaps

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I'm actually willing to know if the following lemma is true or not. (If true, how to proof it or else what is the counterexample?)

**Lemma**. Given two sequence $s_1 = x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ and $s_2=x_{i_1},...,x_{i_n}$, where $s_2$ is a permutation of $s_1$, and both of these sequences satisfies the constraint $C$ ($C$ is a set of variable pairs, where $(x_i, x_j)\in C$ means that $x_i$ should appear before $x_j$ in $C$). Then $s_1$ can be transformed into $s_2$ with **only** a bunch of **safe swaps**, i.e. swaps that never break the constraints in $C$.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the bubblesort algorithm to the first sequence, using the second sequence as the definition of the sort order. In the bubblesort algorithm a correctly ordered pair is never swapped.